# AngularJS TemplateCache

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

I am trying to generate templatecache using `gulp-angular-templatecache` and combine it with Angular script into one JS file.

gulp task:

```
gulp.task('generatetemplatecache', function () {
    return gulp.src(['dev/app/**/*.tpl.html'])
    .pipe(minifyHTML({quotes: true}))
    .pipe(templateCache({ module:'templateCache', standalone:true }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/app'));
});
```

This is basically how output looks like:

```
var app = angular.module("app",['templateCache']);
angular.module("templateCache", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {$templateCache.put("test.tpl.html","<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\"><head><meta charset=\"UTF-8\"><title>My Title</title></head><body></body></html>");
$templateCache.put("layout/popover.tpl.html","<h3 class=\"popover-title\">Click</h3><div class=\"popover-content\"><table style=\"width:600px\" class=\"table\"><tr ng-repeat=\"customer in customers\"><td>{{customer.name}}</td><td>{{customer.street}}</td></tr></table>ss</div>");
```

But the problem is, I found that it does not load from templatecache. Everytime when angular need the template, it still grab the original template html file. If that html file is not available, then it will have trouble displaying it.

Why is it doesn't work? Any part I am doing wrong? The url in the template cache is relative to the `index.html` or to the root of domain?

Comment: What do you mean when you say its grabbing the original file?  Meaning that you change the HTML file and you still see old changes in the browser?

Comment: @sma I mean it still need the original file to be in place. If I take away the template html file, it will have trouble loading it.

Comment: Can you post the gulp task you use to create the template file?

Comment: @sma I have posted my gulp task for generate the template cache.

Comment: So this should be creating a new file called templates.js, correct?  I'm assuming you are loading this file somehow and then adding it as a dependency to your main module?

Comment: @sma Yes. But I combine template.js with other js into one all.js and I also add that dependency to main module.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to check is to make sure the pathing is correct when you create your template file.

For example, in my application, all of my source code is organized this way:

```
modules
   |---user
      |---user-controller.js
      |---user-service.js
      |---user.html

   |---navigation
      |---navigation-controller.js
      |---header.html
      |---footer.html
```

So, in my router or in any directives for `templateUrl` properties, I reference my HTML files like:

```
modules/user/user.html
```

So, that being said, in my Gulpfile when I create my templateCache file, I specify a root of 'modules' so that each of the files are given a key in the templateCache equal to this path.  Such as:

```
gulp.task('templates', function () {
    gulp.src('./app/modules/**/*.html')
        .pipe(angularTemplatecache('templates.js', {
            standalone: true,
            root: "modules"
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/templates'));
});
```

This pathing issue may be why you're having trouble loading them if all other config issues are correct (i.e. you are loading the templates.js file correctly, you are including it as a module dependency on your app)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use another gulp [plugin](https://github.com/laxa1986/gulp-angular-embed-templates) which can read your routes,directives and replace the templateUrl with the template referenced in the templateUrl.

```
src
+-hello-world
  |-hello-world-directive.js
  +-hello-world-template.html
```

hello-world-directive.js:

```
angular.module('test').directive('helloWorld', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        // relative path to template
        templateUrl: 'hello-world-template.html'
    };
});
```

hello-world-template.html:

```
<strong>
    Hello world!
</strong>
```

gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var embedTemplates = require('gulp-angular-embed-templates');

gulp.task('js:build', function () {
    gulp.src('src/scripts/**/*.js')
        .pipe(embedTemplates())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

gulp-angular-embed-templates will generate the following file:

```
angular.module('test').directive('helloWorld', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template:'<strong>Hello world!</strong>'
    };
});
```